# Two between separated with an AND

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to have 2 between in 1 SQL query separated with an "AND"?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM t 
 WHERE (x BETWEEN '48.3' and '49.3') 
   AND (y BETWEEN '1.8' and '3.8');
```

This will work with an OR but won't with an AND.

```
***************************************
|   id   |  x    |   y   |    name     |
|    1   | 48.5  |  2.8  |   patrick   |
|    2   | 48.9  |  1.9  |    Sam      |
|    3   | 49.0  |  5.0  |    Jon      |
```

Comment: Of course it works.

Comment: You can answer this yourself by trying to run the query.

Comment: The wording of this question is bad. I don't think he is asking if it works.

Comment: If you're not getting any results, make sure there's a record that satisfies both conditions are the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote a post because it was faster than running the query.

Comment: Is `x` and `y` really string data types? They look like decimal.

Comment: Agreed, if those are meant to be numerical values, your BETWEEN will not work as you expect.

Comment: @JChri you should always test before posting on SO

Comment: Also, how is it possible writing the question was faster than running the query?

Comment: "Yeah, I wrote a post because it was faster than running the query. "  There is something wrong with your database, That would be the best thing to fix

Comment: I obviously tried the query before writting a post and annoy people! :l

Comment: @Joni I do have 2 results out of 10 that meet both of the conditions

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f72b08/2/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value are number you could  use

```
  SELECT * FROM t 
  WHERE  x BETWEEN 48.3 and 49.3 
  AND y BETWEEN 1.8 and 3.8
```

Comment: the values are numbers inside a varchar column, I assumed I could not do my query without quotes. It should also work with the quotes as Aaron Dietz commented but for some reason it doesn't. Thanks